# Tightening brass piano lamp arms—no obvious method

Tags: repair, lamp

This was a very expensive lamp 35 years ago.  The two rotating pivot points have to adjustment screw or nut.  They were held by friction but now won’t hold at all.

There is a brass “cap” which I assumed concealed an adjustment nut as this is the only way the parts could hold together.  But I’ve been unable to remove or even budge it.  Screwdrivers and wedges driven into the gap between the cap and base seem to only bend the brass and lubricant hasn’t helped.  See photos.  I can’t figure out a better tool or approach. Appreciate thoughts.  [image]

Comment: Will the brass cap turn, so it unscrews from the arm?  Is there a set screw somewhere?  Are there screws behind the large brass flat plate that the hings is mounted on, so the hinge can be removed?  Is there a brand and model number?

Comment: Yea, I would also bet it unscrews.

Comment: Thanks.  I can’t get a grip on it to unscrew.  There are no set screws or other obvious restraints on the brass cap.  I guess I could use some sort of gripping plier.

Comment: A (small) strap wrench, or pad the jaws of locking piers (Vise-Grips® or knockoffs) so they grip but don't ding up the brass are what leaps to mind, based on the picture. Some such things will have slot or pinholes for use with specialized spanners (search "watch crab" far an example of the type.) I can't spot any in the picture, though.